Effect of multiplying message by $q/2$ LWE
I have recently started learning about the LWE problem, and I am wondering about how multiplying the message bit $\mu \in \mathbb{Z}_2$, affects the encoding of this message.
The LWE-based cryptosystem I am looking at is loosely based on the following: https://cims.nyu.edu/~regev/papers/pqc.pdf, described by this paper in Algorithm 5 (pg. 19).
I have been told that a possible method of encrypting this message bit is:
$$\left(u=A^Tr,v=p^Tr+e_2+\left\lfloor\frac{q}{2}\right \rceil\mu\right)$$
where $(A,p=As+e_1)$ is the public key, $r$ is a column vector uniformly chosen from $\{-\beta , -\beta+1, \cdots, \beta-1,\beta \}$, $q$ is the modulus, and $e_2$ is some small error.
I have also been told that a valid method of encryption is computing $v=p^Tr+2e_2+\mu$, and these two methods differ in which binary bit the actual message is stored in. My question is why do we multiply the message bit $\mu$ by $q/2$? Is there maybe a small $2\times 2 $ example that illustrates this well? Is it true that the multiplying the error $e_2$ by 2 rather than the message bit by $q/2$ changes how the message bit is stored in binary?
Also how does this generalise if I want my message bit to come from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for some $n$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}_2$?
Thanks so much!!

Both things are true. I'll discuss multiplying by $(q/2)$ (I like it more).
First, it is worth thinking what happens if we do not multiply by $(q/2)$.
Say that we encrypt by mapping
$$
m\mapsto (\vec a, b:=\langle \vec a, \vec s\rangle + e + m)
$$
where arithmetic is performed $\bmod q$, $|e|$ is small, $\vec s$ is secret, and $\vec a$ is uniform.
This is actually secure.
We don't do it because it is unclear how to decrypt.
The obvious first thing to do is to compute
$$
b - \langle \vec a, \vec s\rangle = m + e.
$$
Here, it is unclear what to do though.
If we instead had $m = (q/2)m'$ for $m'\in\{0,1\}$, then we could try to recover $m'$ from $m + e = (q/2)m' + e$.
This is actually easy to do, via computing
$$
\lfloor (m + e) / (q/2)\rceil
$$
Provided $|e| < q/4$, this will equal $m'$ exactly.
This is because, for $x\in\mathbb{Z}$,  $\lfloor x + e\rceil = x$ provided $|e| < 1/2$.
So
$$
\lfloor (m+e) / (q/2)\rceil = \lfloor m' + e / (q/2)\rceil = m'
$$
provided $|e| / (q/2) < 1/2\iff |e| < q/4$.
So, scaling $m$ is done so that we can actually decrypt, by post-processing the noisy value $(q/2)m'+e$ with a form of error correction.
Scaling $e$ (rather than $m$) achieves a similar goal (but with a different error correction step).

To handle $m\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, there are two things you can do

Decompose $m$ somehow (for example in binary $m = \sum_i m_i 2^i$), and encrypt each bit separately, or
Scale by $(q/n)$ instead (or something close to it, like $\Delta := \lfloor q/n\rfloor$), which only tolerates errors $|e| < \Delta/2 \approx q/(2n)$.

Both have their merits. For example, most LWE-based crypto systems actually use so-called Ring Learning with Errors (RLWE). In RLWE, you can encrypt $n$ (typically $n\in[512, 1024]$) values  simultaneously with no overhead. So if you don't need homomorphic capabilities, the first option is much more attractive, as otherwise you're wasting the $n-1$ other "slots" of your ciphertext.

As for "where the message is stored", the idea is that a message encoded as $m(q/2)$ stores the message "in the top" of a value $\bmod q$.
For a specific example, let $q = 257$.
Then (in python3) bin(q) = '0b100000001', and bin(q//2) = '0b0$\color{red}{1}$0000000'.
So $(q/2)m$ chooses to set the red bit or not.
One can extract this bit by computing (for $m' := (q/2)m+e$) $\lfloor m'/(q/2)\rceil$, as mentioned before.
This situation starts getting very nuanced very fast when wants to talk about it more though.
As an example, when talking about the "bits" of values $\bmod q$, one needs to fix a bit representation of values $\bmod q$.
There are two competing ones

"balanced", where $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z} := [-q/2, q/2)\cap\mathbb{Z}$. This is generally used for implementations leveraging signed arithmetic.
one can also set $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z} := [0, q)\cap\mathbb{Z}$. This is generally used for implementations leveraging unsigned arithmetic.

In my examples above, I was implicitly leveraging the balanced representation when defining the condition $|e| < q/4$, and the other representation when demonstrating bin(q) and bin(q//2).
It's a little weird to talk about the bit pattern of a value in the balanced representation as the location of the sign bit will be dependent on the bitwidth of the underlying numeric type, so representing $\bmod q$ arithmetic using 8, 16, 32 bit signed types (etc) will yield different bit patterns.
To try to be very clear, I'll switch to the second representation below.
Note here that the bound $|e| < q/4$ no longer really makes sense (the error should be in $[0,q)\cap\mathbb{Z}$ as well).
One can fix this by using the adjusted absolute value
$$
|e| = \max(e, q-e).
$$
This absolute value appears in other times one tries to put an absolute value on $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$, like the lee distance in coding theory.
In terms of this absolute value, $|e| < q/4$ can be written as $e\in[0,q/4)\cup (3q/4, q)$.
Our error correction should then send values $m' := (q/2)m+e$ in the above interval to the value of $m = 0$, and values outside of this interval to $m = 1$.
For $q$ a power of $2$, I think one can do this membership test by checking if the XOR of the top 2 bits of the noisy message are 0 ($m = 0$) or 1 ($m = 1$).
So, in this special case, you should be able to formally say that the message is stored in (XOR of the) top bits.
For power of two $q$, the fact that $m + 2e$ stores the message in the bottom bit should also be clear.
For general $q$ not a power of two, I don't think the story is this clean though. I also don't know if there's a clean picture if one represents values in $[-q/2, q/2)\cap \mathbb{Z}$.
Perhaps one can replace the XOR of the top two bits with the XOR of the sign bit and next-highest bit.
I've always interpreted "the message is in the top/bottom" as generalizing the very clear picture one can get (for $q = 2^k$, using the unsigned arithmetic representation) to general $q$ and general representations in like a "vibes" type of way personally.

Thanks!! This is really well explained. Two follow-up questions: is it not possible to just compute $\lfloor m+e \rceil$ if we don't multiply by $q/2$ so long as $|e|<1/2$?  And I'm still not clear on how scaling $e$ or scaling by $m$ affects where the message is stored in binary expansion.

@MathematicallyUnsound Yes, but $e$ is typically distributed on $\mathbb{Z}$ with some constant standard deviation (precise numbers can differ, but $\geq 1$), so this $|e|<1/2\implies e = 0$, which happens only rarely. I'll write some more about the "where the message is stored" thing.

This makes so much more sense now, thanks so much for the extremely detailed writeup; it is so helpful for someone new to this area!!
